# Creating Tenant in FusionAuth with java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, fusionauth

How to write code to create new Tenant with fusionAuthClient?
So that I can create a new Tenant with an API call.

```
Tenant  createTenant = new Tenant()
TenantRequest request = new TenantRequest(tenant);
        ClientResponse<TenantResponse, Errors> response = fusionAuthClient.createTenant(null, request);
```

What should I write in Tenant(), I had .with() and tried to configure it, but it keeps throwing NullPointerException.
The null pointer exception is on
`.with(tenant -> tenant.externalIdentifierConfiguration.changePasswordIdGenerator.type = SecureGeneratorType.randomBytes)`

and there are 12 NullPointerException on the Required Parameters.
I tried to copy the config parameters from other Tenant that i created in FusionAuth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the API docs in conjunction with the client libraries.

https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/tenants/#create-a-tenant

indicates that a number of attributes are required.

It might be easier for you to copy an existing tenant by retrieving a tenant, tweaking the values and creating a new one.

Comment: I tried to create it with all the required attributes but for some reason this one `tenant.externalIdentifierConfiguration.changePasswordIdGenerator.type = SecureGeneratorType.randomBytes)` throws an NullPointerException.
But I could create a new one by retrieving another tenant and tweaking some valuse Thank you for that :)

Comment: I found the solution for thah NullPointerException.
I created `ExternalIdentifierConfiguration externalIdentifierConfiguration = new ExternalIdentifierConfiguration();
        `
and just did  
`externalIdentifierConfiguration.changePasswordIdGenerator = new SecureGeneratorConfiguration(32, SecureGeneratorType.randomBytes);`
        
and it didnt throw any nullPointerExceptions. Created separated Configurations that were required and set them in new Tenant and it worked